# Next Auth authorize request header is of wrong type

Tags: next.js, header, credentials, next-auth

I am trying to make Credentials based authentication to my project. However, when I sign in from the default sign in page the request is of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" even though in my [...nextauth].ts file specify the header to be of type "application/json". What am I doing wrong or how can I change the request header to be of type "application/json" correctly?

Here is my [...nextauth].ts file:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
        providers: [
            CredentialsProvider({
                name: "Credentials",
                credentials: {
                    email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "example@company.com" },
                    password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
                },
                async authorize(credentials) {
                    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            email: credentials?.email,
                            password: credentials?.password,
                        }),
                    })
                    const user = await res.json()

                    if (user) {

                        return user

                    } else {

                        return null
                    }
                }
            })
        ],

        session: {
            strategy: "jwt",
        }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I've tried to identify the problem from the tutorial I was watching and searching online for similar problems but couldn't find anyone having similar problem. Seems like the aforementioned code should work but for some reason for me the content-type header is still wrong.